# Discrete Mathematics - How to Express the phrase "There is no one who did action y"

Tags: discrete-mathematics, quantifiers

Let's say $P(x,y)$ means $x$ sent an e-mail to $y$.

If I want to say that no one has sent a message to Jean, then aren't there multiple ways to do this?

$\neg Ǝx(P(x, Jean))$

But I can also say

$∀x(\neg P(x, Jean))$
Aren't these equivalent? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you have rediscovered an important principle in logic. See, for example, here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantification#Negation

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The "negative" of "there is" is the same as "all" who "haven't."